# Image upload in ActionText not linking to S3 after export / import Database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, rails-activestorage, actiontext

I'm using ActionText for my blog, last week I backed up my database to import to new server. But after I imported my backup SQL, all images uploaded by ActionText are not linking correctly to S3. Other all image and new image working correctly, but only old images uploaded by ActionText.

The URL the old blob is currently using is the rail/active_storage/ storage URL and I need it to use the S3 URL I have set in the storage.yml file.

[image: Images uploaded from file field are linking correctly]

Images uploaded from file field are linking correctly

[image: But old images uploaded from ActionText textarea are getting wrong]

But old images uploaded from ActionText textarea are getting wrong

I checked S3 bucket and make sure all images are stored in S3 bucket.

Can you teach me how to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Check the URL generated on the browser and make sure it points to the correct location of the image in S3

Comment: @user11350468 The URL generated on the browser not linking to S3, it still "rails/active_storage/blobs/...."